# "Then this" vs "Then that"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, this-that

I have the following paragraph:

> We often write hundreds of lines of code to express simple concepts. This code takes time to develop and maintain - and if you’re writing  tests, then **that** time doubles.

I've pasted into both Grammerly and Word, but neither offer a correction.

I'm not confident if it should be **this** or **that**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that either is fine.  Both refer to the *time to develop and maintain*, and the difference in how it sounds is minimal to my ear.

However, the implication here is that you are specifically referring to doubling the amount of time *developing* and *maintaining*.  That means you see writing tests as a subset of developing or maintaining.  If that's not the intent, and you want to refer to time more generally (such as the total project time), then you can simply use **the** instead.